# .net - How to get the test cases present in a test set using HP ALM 12.5

Tags: c#, .net, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

Below query is used to get the test cases present in a test set.But the response returns all the test cases present in the project irrespective of the test set id passed in the query.

https://almamex1253qc.saas.hpe.com/qcbin/rest/domains/[domain]/projects/[project]/test-instances?page-size=max&start-index=1&query%3D%7B%7Btest-set.id%5B[id]%5D%7D%7D;%20test.user-template-07[SIT%20OR%20"Release%20Testing"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean the test instances in a test set and this URL works for me:

```
https://alm/qcbin/rest/domains/[domain]/projects/[project]/test-instances/?query={cycle-id[1782]}
```

Comment: thank you. This query returns the test instances present in the test set.  I want to get the test instances based on the Test Stage(SIT/UAT/Releasetesting) as well. Please provide inputs.

Comment: Hm, what do you mean with Test Stages? Could it be that this is a user defined field in your test sets or test instances?